# Need Winhlp32.exe

Tags: windows, windows-vista, help-files

I know that that WinHelp is discontinued. No more included since Windows Vista. However, while Vista was still supported by Microsoft, I still could install it. Now, no more. Every time I got error in my Windows Vista related to run old software using winhlp32.exe, I am always directed to this Microsoft [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5143). From there I can download a package file, name Windows6.0-KB917607-x86.exe. Unfortunately, it is not allowed to download the required file to run *.hlp file.

Now, I need that Windows Vista/Windows 7's WinHlp32.exe that I can copy and put manually to my C:\Windows. Where can I get it? Can someone help or share?

Answer (score 5):

Windows has two types of help files. The older ones have `.hlp` as their
file extension, and the newer ones `.chm`.

They may be downloaded from:

- The `.hlp` package as downloaded from Microsoft no longer works.
  One that works can be downloaded from
  [majorgeeks](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/winhlp32_for_windows_10.html).
- The `.chm` one can be downloaded from Microsoft
  [HTML Help Workshop and Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138) .

Comment: No, it is not. The link you shared contains: htmlhelp.exe, HelpDocs.zip, & htmlhelpj.exe only. No WinHlp32.exe as I asked.

Comment: You are right - this is for `.chm` files. I added above the one for `.hlp`.

Comment: HTML Help Workshop and Documentation and all in [Microsoft HTML Help Downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/microsoft-html-help-downloads) are 404. Archived links: [HTMLhelp](http://web.archive.org/web/20160201063255/http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/9/0A939EF6-E31C-430F-A3DF-DFAE7960D564/htmlhelp.exe) and [HelpDocs](http://web.archive.org/web/20160314043751/http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/9/0A939EF6-E31C-430F-A3DF-DFAE7960D564/helpdocs.zip).