# Where is the Microsoft HTML (CHM) Help Viewer stored?

Tags: windows, windows-8, chm, help-files

Sometime ago I messed with opening chm files. I set a pdf viewer as the default app for viewing chm files and now I want the Microsoft HTML help Viewer to be set as default chm viewer. The problem is Im not able to find the app either in the System32 folder or in the Windows folder. If somebody can tell me where exactly the Microsoft HTML Help Viewer is stored it would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: Right-click a `.chm` file, do you see HTML Viewer?

Comment: @harrymc No. I don't see it.

Comment: Then you need to reinstall it. This post shows where to download it: https://superuser.com/questions/1419313/need-winhlp32-exe

Answer (score 1):

To reinstall the Microsoft HTML help Viewer, download and install from
[this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1419313/need-winhlp32-exe).

Afterword, run
*Settings > Apps > Default apps > Choose default applications by f‌ile type*,
scroll down to `.chm`, click on the PDF viewer name and select
"Microsoft® HTML Help Executable".